# how to post dynamic row text box values using when checkbox is clicked in php

Tags: php, laravel

I am creating pdf using  dynamically text box values  when the row check box values are clicked,

i need to print the data, the three textboxes are manual entry, and three more fetched from the database, i have a checkbox it contains id from the table, using these check box, when user clicks the checkbox only want to print that corresponding  row only.

when i click check box  row by row its prints the data correctly, when i miss one row it takes the example i click 1,2,3 row  means  print will be 1,2,3 but when i click 1,2,4 means it always print same 1,2,3  row.

the coding is

```
<td><input type='text' name='rollno[]'   class="txt" value="" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='pieceno[]' readonly  value="<?php echo $item['pieceno'] ?>"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='wpieceno[]' readonly  value="<?php echo $item['wpieceno'] ?>"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='meter[]' readonly value="<?php echo $item['passmts'] ?>" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='points[]' readonly value="<?php echo $item['points'] ?>"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='pts[]'  readonly value="<?php echo $item['pts'] ?>"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='gross[]'  ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='net[]'   ></td>
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="ids[]"value="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>" /></td>
```

the controller code is

```
$das=count($_POST['ids']);
for($i=0;$i<$das;$i++)
{

 $order = array('rollno'=>$_POST['rollno'][$i],'pieceno'=>$_POST['pieceno'][$i],'wpieceno'=>$_POST['wpieceno'][$i], 'points'=>$_POST['points'][$i],'pts'=>$_POST['pts'][$i],'meter'=>$_POST['meter'][$i],
'gross'=>$_POST['gross'][$i],'net'=>$_POST['net'][$i],'ids'=>$_POST['ids'][$i]         );
}
```

Comment: your question is rather vague, mind rephrase it? also, your code rather inconsistent, you are using `{{..}}` and a plain `<?php echo ... ?>`. and, we need to narrow down your problem, ie. in pdf generation (what package/library did you use? how you use it?) or in controller that accept the data - don't forget to post these code too if it might help.

Comment: mm, k ,I am using Thujohn pds for get print pdf,

Comment: i need to print the data, the three textboxes are manual entry, and three more fetched from the database, i have a checkbox it contains id from the table, using these check box, when user clicks the checkbox, only print that corresponding  row only

Comment: when i click check box  row by row its prints the data correctly, when i miss one row it takes the example i click 1,2,3 row  means  print will be 1,2,3 but when i click 1,2,4 means it always print same 1,2,3 checked row

Comment: uh, well, the request in ajax or in form post request? anyway, have you tried to `dd(..)` the incoming request to your server? is it possible to post the controller code that serves that page and the one that accept the request to accept your checked checkbox value?

Comment: mm it accepts checkbox value  when user clicks 4 row checkbox , the checkbox value 4 is passed but textbox values 1 is passed