# how to post textbox values when checkbox is checked

Tags: php, laravel

I have a multiple text boxes and also checkbox, when I click that checkbox it has `array[0][1]` values, but textbox has `array[1][2][3][4][5][6]` value. what is problem?

```
<td><input type='text' name="rollno[]"   class="txt" value="" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name="pieceno[]" readonly  value="{{$item['pieceno']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='wpieceno[]' readonly  value="{{$item['wpieceno']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='meter[]' readonly value="{{$item['passmts']}}" ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='points[]' readonly value="{{$item['points']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='pts[]'  readonly value="{{$item['pts']}}"></td> 
<td><input type='text' name='gross[]'  ></td>
<td><input type='text' name='net[]'   ></td>
<td><input type='text' name="id[]"  value="{{ $item['id']}}">
<td><input type="checkbox"  name="ids[]"value="{{$i}}" /></td>
```

Comment: @AmitRajput Minor formatting error, last 2 lines are now visible, so you might remove your close vote now

Comment: Checkboxes are only sent to the script in `$_POST` or `$_GET` if they are actually checked. So I assume you only checked the first 2 checkboxes? So you have to test for the existance of a checkbox before using it `isset()`

Comment: clarification, basically you wish to filter the textbox based on the checkbox? looks like you're asking [*the same unsolved question*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611946/how-to-post-dynamic-row-text-box-values-using-when-checkbox-is-clicked-in-php)